# Is it possible to add multiple pie3D charts in one figure in R?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I did made three pie3D (plotrix) pictures in R.

- 1 with the population as a whole
- 1 for the adults of the population
- 1 for children of the population

Now, it are three separate figures. Is it possible to add them together to 1 figure?

ggarange will not work because pie3D is not a ggplot function.
Does anybody knows other options?

Comment: Could you please share some code and data using `dput`? So we can reproduce and help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In R base plotting you can set some graphical parameters with `par` to determine the output. Type `?par` in the console to see the help file. The following is an excerpt from the helpfile:

*mfcol, mfrow*

- *A vector of the form c(nr, nc). Subsequent figures will be drawn in an nr-by-nc array on the device by columns (mfcol), or rows (mfrow), respectively.*

With the following code and mockup data, you can arrange the three plots in a row of 3 "columns"

```
library(plotrix)

## some mocked up data
x1 <- c(4, 5, 9, 3, 6)
x2 <- c(7, 2, 1, 1, 4)
x3 <- c(5, 5, 2, 1, 1)
## some common labels
labels <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

## set to 1 row, 3 columns
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
pie3D(x1, labels = labels, explode = .1)
pie3D(x2, labels = labels, explode = .1)
pie3D(x3, labels = labels, explode = .1)
## re-set to 1 row, 1 column
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

yielding this graph:
[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you want.